# "Site Icon" refuses image with transparency

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been working on building my first WordPress site, [DontAskMeAgain](http://dontaskmeagain.com), and its been going well. I've gotten everything ready, but I can't seem to be able to set the favicon or "Site Icon" from inside the customization menu on the site.

### Selecting the "Site Icon"

1. Go to the "Customizing Site Identity" portion of the website.[image: Customizing Site Identity]
2. At the bottom left corner I press the "Select Image" button. It then popups up the following.[image: Select Image]
3. Next I press the first image in the top right corner, which then enables the "Select" button.[image: Select]
4. I finally press the "Select" button which should then go to a "Crop Image" section. Instead it just disables the "Select" button and deselects the image I want to be the "Site Icon."[image]

### Debugging

By default I thought this might have to be a problem with the code, or permissions inside the WordPress directory folder. I went inside it and all of it was set to the right permissions. I decided to see if another image would work.

1. I selected the image right beside the red icon.[image: Comp Shop Icon]
2. Next pressed the "Select" button and it went right on to the "Crop Image" section.[image: Crop Image]

### Difference?

The only difference that I was able to find between the [First Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIYbY.png) and [Second Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QzlA.png) is that the first has some transparency in it, and the second doesn't.

Does anybody know what this issue is? And do they at all know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can fix it by using the wonderful [Yoast SEO Plugin](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/).
This plugin allows you to define an image for the whole devices automatically (OG Tag) and keep the transparency.

Comment: Thank you for recommending the Yoast SEO plugin, but it only sets the image to be "used if the post/page being shared does not contain any images." The "Site Icon" is the favicon, and this is to my knowledge not what Yoast SEO can do. If I'm missing something, please tell me.

Comment: Hello, In this case you can add manually a favicon by modifying the header.php. Add this line : <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="your-logo-url.png" /> in the <head> tag

Comment: I was hoping to keep use the UI for it, but I guess that thats the only way to do it. Thank you very much for your help! If you want to add that into your answer I'll mark it as the answer to my question.